When launching a new client bot via my main bot, the stateful handlers don't work?
When a separate bot is launched through a function by a user of my bot, i.e. he creates his own bot through my bot, then when processing event handlers if I specify state=‘*’ everything works, but if I specify a specific state as an argument, the handler stops executing.
async def start_client_project_bot(user_id, name, token):
    try:
        client_bot = Bot(token=token, parse_mode="HTML")
        client_storage = MemoryStorage()
        client_dp = Dispatcher(client_bot, storage=client_storage)

        from project_create import base
        base.register_client_handlers(client_dp)

        await client_dp.start_polling()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"{e}", exc_info=True)

def register_client_handlers(dp):

    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state="*")
    async def start_project_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        kb = await create_keyboard('main_message_kb', 1)
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        await state.update_data(user_id=user_id)
        await message.answer(bot_navigation.messages_data['main_msg'], reply_markup=kb)

    @dp.callback_query_handler(text="start_exchange", state="*")
    async def select_exchange_direction(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):

        state_info = await state.get_data()
        user_id = state_info['user_id']

        
        kb = await create_keyboard('exchange_directions_kb', 1)
        await call.message.edit_text(bot_navigation.messages_data['direction_select_msg'], reply_markup=kb)

        await state.set_state("get_send_coins_list")

    @dp.callback_query_handler(state="get_send_coins_list")
    async def get_send_coins_list(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
        current_state = await state.get_state()

        direction = call.data
        await state.update_data(exchange_direction=direction)
        kb = await get_coin_list('payin')
        kb = await back_button(kb)
        await call.message.edit_text(bot_navigation.messages_data['select_send_coin_msg'], reply_markup=kb)

I tried different methods of specifying states, but nothing worked, and I checked accordingly without specifying a state - in that case it worked. But for the bot to work properly it is necessary to specify states
